# Проверка содержимого java коллекции на jsp странице

Tags: java-ee, jsp

Доброй ночи!
Есть фрагмент jsp страницы, который выводит список пользователей (из контроллера получает коллекцию). Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при выводе в таблицу пропускались пользователи, которые есть в другой коллекции.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100px; width: 300px; overflow: auto">
    <c:if test="${!empty listUsers}">
        <c:forEach items="${listUsers}" var="user">
            <c:if test="${!company.responsibleUser.contains(user)}">
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <c:if test="${!empty company.id}">
                    <td disabled="true"><a href="<c:url value='/addresponsible/${user.id}/${company.id}/' />"
                    style="text-decoration: none" />${user.username}</td>
                </c:if>
            </table>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</div>
```

В jsp особо не разбираюсь, пытаюсь написать такое условие
(строка 4)
На сколько корректно вообще такое писать, и как решить задачу, чтобы в случае наличия конкретного user в коллекции responsibleUser не выводить его в таблицу?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение:

```html
<c:if test="${!company.responsibleUser.contains(user)}">
```